# iOS 10.0.2 notification vs 10.2 notification

Tags: push-notification, ios10, ios10.2

In my build I am not using `UNUserNotificationCenter.h` class for handling the notification in the app.

I am using old method.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

 // handling notification with this method.

}
```

In `iOS 10.0.2` not able to handle the notification and `iOS 10.2` everything working fine.

`xcode version 8.1.`

Comment: please check this link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54322

Comment: thanx   @Jayesh Thanki